# Regex to find and remove ONLY diacritic or explicitly specified characters on a text

Tags: regex, diacritics, data-cleaning

I have a text which contains some diacritic characters. I want to find them using regex but I haven't managed to find and remove only such characters (plus some others such as %^*$#).

The closest I have gotten was using unicode, but it matched way more than only diacritic characters. Can someone help with this? It seems simple but I've wasted a few hours on this already...

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need specifically the regular expression? It should be easy using, for example, the [`iconv`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) library and transliteration.

Comment: Because I am cleaning data from a data source using a specific tool that only supports regular expressions for this type of job

Comment: Are you just trying to remove the _Mark_ itself or the character it modifies as well ? According to Wikipedia, the _marks_ are `112 code points Combining Diacritical Marks: U+0300 - U+036F`. To remove the marks just put them into a class `[\x{300}-\X{36F}]` to match them.

Comment: @sln I tried putting like that `[\u0300-\u036F].+` but it didn't work, didn't match any...

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to find the valid characters in the string and discard the rest?

Comment: @maraca Yeah, it's an option... What would you propose in this case? :)

Comment: Sorry @LarissaLeite, those are just combining marks. Diacritic marks can be different, and of different values/locations in different languages. Can you paste an example that I can look at with a hex viewer for Unicode I have?

Comment: Something like `[A-Za-z0-9\s,.:;?!/_-]+` and then concatenate all the matches.

Comment: That last highlighted class had a Unicode character for the `-`, my bad, this is the one you should try `[\u0300-\u036F\u1AB0-\u1AFF\u1DC0-\u1DFF\u20D0-\u20FF\uFE20-\uFE2F]`. Its a list for Extended, Suplement, Symbols, Half-Marks as well.

Comment: Anyway, see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character. To get affected characters to form _the glyph_ is not so straight forward. Btw, if you use something like keeping only ascii, you end up throwing out the baby with the bathwater. Good luck !

Comment: Ok, I checked. That regex is specific for _Latin_ script's only. I does work for Latin, I tested it. It would have to be modified to include all the other languages you may need it for. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic